# Install AsyncStorage React Native doesnt work

Tags: react-native, installation, asyncstorage

If i want to add "npm install @react-native-community/async-storage" in the terminal.
There is this error and i dont know why.

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE

npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree

npm ERR!

npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined

npm ERR! Found: react@16.14.0

npm ERR! node_modules/react

npm ERR!   react@"^16.13.0" from the root project

npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8" from @react-native-community/async-storage@1.12.1

npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage

npm ERR!     @react-native-community/async-storage@"*" from the root project

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:

npm ERR! peer react@"18.1.0" from react-native@0.70.6

npm ERR! node_modules/react-native

npm ERR!   peer react-native@">=0.59" from @react-native-community/async-storage@1.12.1

kjf Is it maybe of my react version. If yes how can I change my version

Comment: what is your current react version? in package.json

Answer (score 0):

you have to change your react version to resolve this error.

using **npm install react@[version] --save** cmmand you can change your react Version.

Comment: Do you know which version i need?

Comment: try 18.0.0 it's worked for me.
npm install react@18.0.0 --save

Comment: it didnt work for me :/

Comment: share me your package.json

Answer (score 0):

Try using this `@react-native-async-storage/async-storage` package